# Sending socket to a Wi-Fi controller in Python

Tags: python, sockets, wifi

Is it possible to send socket to a Wi-Fi module? I have a Wi-Fi led controller and I would like to make it possible to control it without connecting manually to the controller.

[image]

Code:

```
def send(text):
ip = "10.10.123.3"
port = 48899

byte_array = convert_to_bytes(text)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((ip, port))
s.send(byte_array)
s.close()
```

The code is working correctly if I'm connecting to it.

Comment: You might be able to spoof communication directly with the LED, but you'd need to study/reverse engineer the protocol it uses to do that so that you could spoof it properly. Why circumvent the controller though?

Comment: Here is the module manual: https://store.comet.bg/download-file.php?id=14702 After sending the socket the module would be able to connect to a network. After a power outage, the device forgets the network. And I would like to make a code that automatically configures the module. Do you think it would be better if I make a code that automatically connects to the "LEDnet" and then sends the sockets?

Comment: You should find out how to make your LED controller connect to your network, instead of creating its own network.

Comment: send("AT+WSSSID=" + ssid)
send("AT+WSKEY=WPA2PSK,AES," + password)
send("AT+WMODE=STA")
send("AT+Z")